# Devexpress XtraGrid columns Text Alignment

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

Devexpress XtraGrid columns Text  Alignment .?

Example:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

You can set your grid column text properties from below settings, please refer screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The VAlignment property that you are referring to will simply vertically align the column header text, not rotate it to be displayed vertically.

There are several example tickets in the DevExpress support center with sample projects demonstrating how to achieve this behavior via the GridView's [GridView.CustomDrawColumnHeader event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawColumnHeadertopic).

See:

- [How to rotate BandedGridColumn or GridColumn caption ?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T258839)
- [Xtra Grid Vertical Headers](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q352492)
- [Display a GridView column header text vertically](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q526800)